# Is there any open source library for reading OCAD files?

Tags: open-source-gis, file-formats, ocad, library

I would like to read map files created by [OCAD](http://ocad.com/) (.ocd). The file format specification is open and available on the web page, but it's binary and complex.

Is there an open source library that can be used for reading these .ocd files?

Comment: Yes, Open Orienteering Mapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, best I can tell the format has no open source parsers. The software itself does support exporting to AI and SVG files, which may be the best bet. Reverse engineering a format such as this is difficult, as it is an intermingling of symbols, raster and vector contents.

Comment: Likely a good answer in 2010, but here in the future there are both OpenOrientereering Mapper as well as my own JavaScript tools - look at the answers below!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to migrate from OCAD to some free & open-source software then, I highly recommend you use**OpenOrienteering Mapper** (OOMapper for short) - cartographic desktop publishing software for creating and printing maps (distributed with symbol sets for orienteering maps, but other symbol sets could be created in easy way directly in OOMapper).

OpenOrienteering Mapper's site - http://www.openorienteering.org/apps/mapper/

As advantage of migrating on OOMapper from OCAD:

- Open Source: The program is completely free, every programmer can improve it.
- Cross-platform: The program works on Android, Windows, macOS and Linux.
- Symbol sets for ISOM2000 (forest), ISSOM2007 (sprint), ISMTBOM (mountain bike), ISSkiOM (ski), and for course design and control description sheets
- Import and export of ocd maps and symbol sets (import: version 6 - 12, export: version 8)
- Georeferencing (based on Proj.4 library)
- Working with various kinds of templates:

  - Images (bmp, jpg, tif, png, gif)
  - GPS tracks (gpx)
  - Vector data (dxf, osm, shp)
  - Maps (ocd, omap, xmap)
  - Georeferencing of templates by world file
- Working with all important symbol types:

  - Points
  - Lines
  - Areas
  - Text
  - Composite symbols
- Drawing and many editing tools for objects
- Printing, PDF and raster image export for getting the map into course setting programs:

  - Overprinting simulation (raster output)
  - CMYK PDF export (vector output)
- Many translations

At this point OpenOrienteering Mapper is free & open-source alternative to OCAD. So, *if you already has some own created maps in `.ocd` (OCAD) or `.dxf` format you could easy open this map for editing in OOMapper* too!

Answer (score 1):

I am working on a number of JavaScript modules to read and work with OCAD files: extract the geometries and other data, export data to various formats liked SVG, PNG, GeoJSON and QGIS. Styling can also be extracted into Mapbox Style Spec.

This is a constant work in progress, but if you're a developer I think you can find it useful:

- https://github.com/perliedman/ocad2geojson (core library)
- https://github.com/perliedman/ocad2tiles (tools for easily generating bitmaps and tiles)
- https://github.com/perliedman/o-scout (experimental web app to work with OCAD and Purple Pen files)

Answer (score 0):

As of now, there is an OCAD viewer available from http://ocad.com/en/downloads/ocad-viewer
This will allow you to open and view .ocd files.

Answer (score 0):

OOM Open Orienteering Mapper can do it for you.
https://github.com/OpenOrienteering/mapper/

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  A minimum length answer (or question) here is about a paragraph.